# Stop LYX from deleting linebreaks

Tags: lyx, line-breaking, paragraphs

Everytime Text is pasted in LYX it delets all linebreaks, which results in one giant paragraph and the user having to add all the linebreaks mannualy.

Is there a way to prevent LYX from deleting the linebreaks and preserve the copied paragraph structure?

Comment: From where did you copy the text? Had this text merely linebreaks between the paragraphs or empty lines?

Comment: @samcarter
It deletes every linebreak. No matter where it is copied from. and no matter weather it is only a linebreak or if there are empty lines. The pasted text always ends up without any paragraph structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ctrl+shift+v instead of ctrl+v for paste (at least, these are the shortcuts on Ubuntu). Alternatively, try Edit > Paste Special > Plain Text.

Comment: Works on windows too